# MonoGame Pipeline

Tags: monogame, xna-content-pipeline

I've been having some problems with the pipeline in MonoGame. I'm using Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 with MonoGame 3.4. I used the installer rather than NuGet if that helps with the problem. Originally the templates went into another users folder and I had to copy them out. I have all of the templates installed in the correct area but when I double click the Content.mgcb icon on the right side of the screen it opens up this file:

```
#----------------------------- Global Properties ----------------------------#

/outputDir:bin/Windows
/intermediateDir:obj/Windows
/platform:Windows
/config:
/profile:Reach
/compress:False

#-------------------------------- References --------------------------------#


#---------------------------------- Content ---------------------------------#
```

Thanks!

Comment: Right click the .mgcb file and choose "Open WIth". What options do you have available? The correct program should be called "Monogame Pipeline"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What it looks like you're seeing is the file opening as a plain text in Visual Studio. I often open the file this way because I find it handy to be able to edit stuff outside the GUI.

As mentioned by @tandersen, if you right click the `Content.mgcb` file in Solution Explorer you can choose "Open With..." to get the following dialog.

[image: MonoGame Content Pipeline Open With Visual Studio]

If you can't see the MonoGame Pipeline Tool in the list you'll need to "Add..." it manually. This can be a little tricky because it installs into an odd folder by default.

On my machine the `Pipeline.exe` is located here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\MonoGame\v3.0\Tools
```

Once you've added it and "Set as Default" it should open by double clicking the `Content.mgcb` file.